# Override django admin action

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a base admin model which I managed to override some fields like inlines, fields, etc but for some reason I cannot override the actions, what am I missing?

```
@admin.register(BaseOrder)
class BaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = BaseOrder
    actions = ['some_action']

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(BaseOrderAdmin):
    model = Order
    actions = []
```

Order model should only have "some_new_action" action but it only has the base admin action 'some_action' so isnt overriden.

Comment: Please, can you post the rest of your `admin.py` code? Also, it might help you reading this part of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#conditionally-enabling-or-disabling-actions) if you haven't done yet.

Comment: Have you registered the models with these Admins?  `admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)`?

Comment: I register actually with the decorator @admin.register(Order)

Comment: @lapinkoira please provide a proper [mcve]. Your last comment doesn't make clear which of the ModelAdmin you register, and we all have better things to do than playing guessing games ;-)

Comment: I edited the question, how can you remove the action from the admin subclass?

Comment: Do you really need to register the `BaseOrderAdmin`? Maybe that can become a mixing with the actions you need and then when you don't need you inherit that mixin.

Comment: If `BaseOrderAdmin` is a base class, you shouldn't register it with admin or assign it a model. That should be handled by the classes that inherit it

Comment: The use case is I develop an admin view which has a lot of functionality and I extend it and reuse it in another admin view, that new admin view shares a lot of the functionality but I just dont need the base admin actions.
Thing is I have managed to override everything I needed, like fields, search_fields, ordering, list_display but why I cannot override actions?

Comment: So instead of registering from the base class, inherit from it and register that class. Your base class is effectively customising the `admin.ModelAdmin`. You wouldn't directly register `ModelAdmin` with your admin site.

Comment: @MikeyLockwood sorry I dont quite understand what you mean with " I dont need to register ModelAdmin?", could you post an answer with an example?

Comment: @lapinkoira I've added an answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to register model twice - in `OrderAdmin` and also in parent class. This can produce some weird effects (like with actions, in your case). Clean way to re-use functionality across ModelAdmin classes is to put it to mixin and then include that mixin wherever needed. Like this:

```
class CommonAdminMixin:
    actions = ['some_action']


@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(CommonAdminMixin, models.Admin):
    actions = []


@admin.register(AnotherModel)
class AnotherAdmin(CommonAdminMixin, models.Admin):
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, nice there is a solution, it just feels wierd you need a mixin for that when other modeladmin attributes can be just straightforward overriden.

Comment: I would look ar it this way: it *happens* that *some* attributes can be straightforward overriden. But here is no guarantee that all attributes can be overridden this way. Django docs do not say that inheritance of model admin classes should work this way.

Comment: `@admin.register(CommonAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin)`is incorrect. You just put the model you want to register the admin class against in the decorator. Also you inherit the mixin in the admin class definition, not the register decorator, usually with the parent class first.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the mixin solution, but I would use a parent class instead which will allow you to call `super()` within the methods without any weirdness.

```py
class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['some_action']


@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    model = Order


@admin.register(AnotherModel)
class AnotherAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    model = AnotherModel
    actions = []
```

You just override `admin.ModelAdmin` in the `BaseAdmin` class and inherit from `BaseAdmin` instead. You can then effectively treat `BaseAdmin` like `admin.ModelAdmin`

Comment: Have you tested it? actions = [] wont override BaseAdmin.actions and AnotherAdmin actions will keep displaying 'some_action'

Comment: @lapinkoira Yes, this structure should work. If you are still having the same issue, you will need to share your full admin classes as there must be something else causing this